# Define an incremental counter with Lua

Tags: macros, luatex, lua, directlua

I would like to receive a suggestion for this example. Really, it is more a question related to Lua scripting.

### Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\directlua{dofile("timer.lua")}

\providecommand{\interval}[1]{
    \directlua{
    tex.print("\string\\textbf{Time estimation}: " .. #1 .. " seconds.".. "\string\\hfill" .. "$t\string\\in" .. "\string\\left[" .. start .. "," .. difference(#1) .. "\string\\right]" .. "$" .. " min.")
}
}
\begin{document}

\frame{\interval{60}}

\frame{\interval{240}}

\end{document}
```

#### `timer.lua`

```lua
#!/usr/bin/lua

function trunc(num, digits)
    local mult = 10 ^ (digits)
    return math.modf(num * mult) / mult
end

start = 0

function difference(increment)
    increment = increment + start
    diff = (increment - start)/60
    return trunc(diff, 2)
end
```

I'm working with

- Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
- This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux).

#### Output desire

I would like to have the acummulation of times, i.e,

- from the first slide `\interval{increment1}` and put `Time estimation: increment1 seconds.                    $t\in\left[start, start+increment1\right]$`.
- and the second slide `\interval{increment2}` and put `Time estimation: increment2 seconds.                     $t\in\left[start+increment1, start+increment1+increment2\right]$`. The default value for start is zero.

Like a recurrence

$$S_{n}=S_{n-1}+S_{n-2},\forall n\geq2.$$

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```lua
--timer.lua:
sum = 0

function difference(increment)
    oldsumstr = string.format("%.2f",sum/60)
    sum = sum + increment
    sumstr = string.format("%.2f",sum/60)
    return oldsumstr,sumstr
end
```

and then:

```
\providecommand{\interval}[1]{
    \directlua{
        local oldsumstr,sumstr = difference(#1)
        tex.print("\string\\textbf{Time estimation}: " .. #1 .. " seconds." ..
            "\string\\hfill" .. "$t\string\\in" .. "\string\\left[" ..
            oldsumstr .. "," .. sumstr .. "\string\\right]" .. "$" .. " min.")
    }
 }
```

This should yield the desired result.

Comment: Very good @frafl, works very `\frame{\interval{60}} \frame{\interval{240}} \frame{\interval{600}} \frame{\interval{55}}`. Thank you.